# Angular.js tabset not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
<div role="main" class="container-fluid theme-showcase">
    <div class="container-fluid" style=" margin-top:3.5em;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center headerContainer" style="padding-top:1.5em">
                <span class="fontHeader">{{test}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2 id="tables">{{test}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="testCtrl">
                <tabset>
                    <tab>
                        <tab-heading>
                            <span>hello</span><em>1</em>
                        </tab-heading>
                        One
                    </tab>
                    <tab heading="Two">Two</tab>
                    <tab heading="Three">Three</tab>
                </tabset>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run my code, it shows up like this:
[image]

I am using yeoman, bootstrap, angular js. Any idea why is angular.js is not recognising it? The code seems to be correct (tabset)Thanks

Comment: Seems working here http://plnkr.co/edit/H3YeA0Qg0LFJrYzAsIZa?p=preview

Comment: Got it to work, turns out angular-ui was not installed

Comment: Also, since ~ angular 1.5, the tags `uib-tabset`, `uib-tab`, `uib-tab-heading` should be used.